# SASS - Passing map through map_merge results in similar looking but not equivalent map

Tags: sass, sass-maps, angular-material-theming

I'm trying to write a function to dynamically apply some transformations to a previously defined map of colours for an angular material theme. The problem is that the result that comes out of the function is *wrong*, somehow.

I've printed the result via the debug log and it looks exactly like the original map, but fails a comparison by keys, and causes errors if I try to feed it to angular material functions.

Here is a simplified demonstration of the issue - you can see that

- `$eenie` and `$meenie` are equivalent
- the results of the function (`$miney` and `$mo`) are also equivalent
- all 4 look identical through debug

What I need to accomplish inside the function is for `$eenie` to be equivalent to `$miney` after having gone through `map_merge`

I suspect that maybe because the key looks a number, it is having some kind of datatype crisis, but I don't know enough about SASS to figure out if that's the case or how to get around it. I've tried using quotes, but that does not seem to be an acceptable input for angular material functions, so I need it to match `$eenie` exactly.

```
@function merge-things($base-palette){
  $result: ();
  @each $hue, $color in $base-palette {
      $result: map_merge($result, (#{$hue}: $color));
  }
  @return $result;
}

$eenie: (
  50: green,
  contrast: (
    50: white,
  ),
);
$meenie: (
  50: green,
  contrast: (
    50: white,
  ),
);

$miney: merge-things($eenie);
$mo: merge-things($miney);



@debug $eenie;    // DEBUG: (50: green, contrast: (50: white))
@debug $meenie;   // DEBUG: (50: green, contrast: (50: white))
@debug $miney;    // DEBUG: (50: green, contrast: (50: white))
@debug $mo;       // DEBUG: (50: green, contrast: (50: white))
@debug 'eenie-meenie #{map-keys($eenie) == map-keys($meenie)}';   // DEBUG: eenie-meenie true
@debug 'eenie-miney #{map-keys($eenie) == map-keys($miney)}';     // DEBUG: eenie-miney false
@debug 'miney-mo #{map-keys($miney) == map-keys($mo)}';           // DEBUG: miney-mo true
```

Comment: Isn't `@debug $mo` supposed to be `(50: green, contrast: (50: white))` since it switches the colors of `$miney`? Or can you clarify what the transformation is meant to do on the map?

Comment: @OluwafemiSule in this example the transformation doesn't do anything. I messed up pasting the debug messages, they should all say green,  contrast white

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `merge-things` function changes the type of keys when interpolation is performed with the key in the map that is a number.

```
@use "sass:map";

$result: map-merge($result, (#{$hue}: $color));
```

The following exercise shows that interpolating a `number` type converts it to `string` type.

```
@use "sass:meta";

$k: 1;

@debug meta.type-of(#{$k}); // string

@debug meta.type-of($k); // number
```

Leave the keys as-is when you build up the new map.

```
-      $result: map-merge($result, (#{$hue}: $color));
+      $result: map-merge($result, ($hue: $color));
```

Comment: Hi where is map_merge defined?

Comment: @gyozokudor That was a typo. The function you need is [map-merge](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/map#merge). You can import it in your sass file with `@use "sass:map"`